# How do I store a password in Cocoa preferences?

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I was going to store a password in my Cocoa application in the `NSUserDefaults` but then I realized that it is stored in plain text.

How do you store password credentials for Cocoa applications?

Answer (score 6):

Passwords should be stored in the Keychain.  You should probably look at the [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) to begin with.  The Keychain exists on both iOS and OS X platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypt it with BCrypt first.

I have an open source BCrypt utility class if you're interested...

[old link deleted]

Comment: Don't bother with this. The keychain already takes care of such details

Comment: OP wanted to know about encryption when using NSUserDefaults, not about Keychain specifically although I agree, Keychain is a good option.  I offered a general purpose solution inline with OP's request.

Comment: Their question was "How do you store password credentials for Cocoa applications?". `NSUserDefaults` was their first thought, but not what they were asking for.

Comment: You neglect the possibility that someone who does want to store encrypted data in NSUserDefaults uses Google and finds this answer. I've +1'd this just to counter the -1, even though I didn't personally find the answer helpful.

Comment: @JasonFuerstenberg the link provided is no longer available could you update it or remove it? The page can be viewed here on [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20121011021330/http://www.jayfuerstenberg.com/blog/bcrypt-in-objective-c).